# Шрифт в web приложении

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Всем привет, недавно столкнулся с такой ситуацией. В web приложении используется `font-family` и три разных типа шрифтов. Например на [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) используются `Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif` но каждый из этих шрифтов может существовать отдельно.

Вопрос в следующем, зачем шрифтов несколько и как и для чего используется каждый из них?

Answer (score 1):

Если у пользователя не будет одного из шрифтов в браузере, то будет использоваться следующий.

Comment: как его может не быть?

Comment: Нету его в бровзере , например старая версия бровзера